# People / Group column looping through nested data

Tags: javascript, rest, sharepoint-rest-api, api, data

I am using Javascript / Jquery to pull list data.  One of the fields is Author, which is a group / people field that allows for multiple users.  I get the data, and I test if there is data in the column then I loop through and append it to a table cell, the problem is how I gather it, I see what its doing, its going thru all the items.  I don't know how to correct it though.

```
    //PRIMARY LIST DATA
    var dat=data.d.results;
//LOOPING THROUGH ALL OF THE DATA   
    for (var i=0;i<dat.length;i++){
//IF THE AUTHOR FIELD IS NOT DEFINED DO ANOTHER FOR LOOP
        if (dat[i].Author0.results === undefined){
            name='No author listed';
        }else {
            for (var j = 0;j < dat[i].Author0.results.length;j++){
                full = dat[i].Author0.results[j].Title;
            }
            name = full;
        }   
    tb+='<tr><td><a href="/Library/'+dat[i].FileLeafRef+'"><span class="doc-icons '+dat[i].File_x0020_Type+'"></span>'+dat[i].FileLeafRef+'</a></td><td>'+dat[i].Content_x0020_Type+'</td><td>'+keywd+'</td><td>'+name+'</td></tr>';
                    } 
                    $('.tb1> tbody').html(tb);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the code showing just the last user? Try this.

```
//PRIMARY LIST DATA
var dat=data.d.results;

//LOOPING THROUGH ALL OF THE DATA 
for (var i=0;i<dat.length;i++){ 
    //IF THE AUTHOR FIELD IS NOT DEFINED DO ANOTHER FOR LOOP
    var authors = dat[i].Author0.results;
    if (!authors){ 
        name='No author listed'; 
    }
    else{
        for (var j = 0;j < authors.length;j++){
            full += authors[j].Title + "; "; 
        }
        name = full;
    }
    tb+='<tr><td><a href="/Library/'+dat[i].FileLeafRef+'"><span class="doc-icons '+dat[i].File_x0020_Type+'"></span>'+dat[i].FileLeafRef+'</a></td><td>'+dat[i].Content_x0020_Type+'</td><td>'+keywd+'</td><td>'+name+'</td></tr>';
}
$('.tb1> tbody').html(tb);
```

Comment: Thank you this works

Comment: Great. Please upvote too.

Comment: much appreciated :) thank you